# How to implement Neumorphism View to React Native for Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I have to create Neumorphism styled UI into React Native project and I'm currently developing for android. I've currently encountered a problem in which shadows properties don't work as expected for android. I then tried using react-native-drop-shadow which I read from this blog:
https://blog.logrocket.com/applying-box-shadows-in-react-native/

Here is my current implementation
[image: The image contains a top shadow but it's very hard to see.]

NeoView.tsx

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, ViewStyle } from "react-native";
import DropShadow from "react-native-drop-shadow";

type NeoViewProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  size?: number;
  style?: ViewStyle;
};

const NeoView = ({ children, size, style }: NeoViewProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <DropShadow style={styles.bottomShadow}></DropShadow>
      <DropShadow style={styles.topShadow}>
        <View
          style={[
            styles.inner,
            { width: size || 40, height: size || 40, borderRadius: 10 },
            style,
          ]}
        >
          {children}
        </View>
      </DropShadow>
    </>
  );
};

export default NeoView;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inner: {
    backgroundColor: "#F0F0F3",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderColor: "#D3D5D8",
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  topShadow: {
    shadowOffset: {
      width: -2,
      height: -2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    shadowColor: "#fff",
  },
  bottomShadow: {
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 2,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    shadowColor: "#7A7987",
  },
});
```

Comment: did you find any thing?

Comment: I believe that it doesn't work well on Android. Shadow in React Native looks better in iOS devices (including the simulators).

Comment: so there is no good solution for inset shadow?

Comment: Yes. As I have answered earlier, shadow in Android is not nice. Flutter, on the other hand, handles shadowing well.